# How can the following second-order ODE be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following ODE is a linear, second-order,non-homogenous equation with variable coefficients. I have tried to get the analytical solution by using the method of Variation of Parameters which in turn requires the solution of the corresponding homogeneous ODE. I can find the solution in Mathematica, but I need to understand the solution steps.

$$ y''(x) + (\frac{a}{x}) y'(x)- (b) y(x) = c$$

Where:
$a,b,c$ are constants

Comment: $y(x) = -c/b$  is a solution if $b\neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it. I am sorry for that.

Comment: Could you post your attempt at variation of parameters?

Comment: @Alex R. Shouldn't we start with solving the homogeneous equation first?

Comment: You have to Frobenius' Method to solve the equation.

Comment: See http://www.its.caltech.edu/~esp/acm95b/frobenius.pdf

Comment: Maple solves this in terms of Bessel functions.  So maybe see if your DE can be transformed to the Bessel DE.